# Can we use Ext.ComponentQuery.query in case id contains a fixed String

Tags: javascript, extjs

Like we can use starts with **Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[id^=User]')** and ends with **Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[id*=User]')**. Do we have something conditional matching by which we can search for a control if it contains a specific string irrespective of its position.

**For Example**: we have a component with id "Submission:AccountNumber:InputText"

we have "AccountNumber" as a static part in component id. I want to write component query which could search for control whose id contains AccountNumber

Comment: Try `'textfield[id/="AccountNumber"]'`

Comment: Sorry it didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

[The official docs of `ComponentQuery`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.ComponentQuery.html) show all possible query operators and have a wide range of examples. In it, you find that there is no direct hit for your search need, but there is a regular expression search available:

```
textfield[id/=AccountNumber]
```

I have [made a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1f8i) which shows that it works correctly only in certain ExtJS versions (namely 4.2.5), and throws different errors in others (6.0.1: "Invalid component id", 4.2.1: "Could not call setTitle of undefined", because the component obviously wasn't found).

There is no other wildcard `ComponentQuery` available.